# Shell script to change password called by php cronjob with strange behavior

Tags: php, shell, cron, ubuntu-12.04

I run a small script to enable pw change via PHP. I know security might be a problem but that is not the current issue.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "############### pw.sh "`date` $1 $2 "##################" >> /cronscripts/cronpw.log
echo "user_$1:$2!" >> /cronscripts/cronpw.log
echo "user_$1:$2" | chpasswd
```

This script works fine

1. When call directly ./pw.sh 5001 pw
2. When called with a small php Skript from the same directory

   ```
   <?php
       echo exec("/cronscripts/pw.sh 5001 'boris'");
     ?>
   ```

But it does not work when called with the same exec command by cronjob run from the root crontab.

Cron calls script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/cronskripte/
echo "###############" `date` "##################" >> /cronscripts/cronuseradd.log
php5 cron_useradd.php >> /cronscripts/cronuseradd.log
```

useradd.php contains:

```
echo exec("whoami"); ==> root

echo exec("/cronscripts/pw.sh $login '$password'");
```

The strange thing is that cronpw.log shows the same as when called with the first 2 methods, but the pw change won't take place. Any ideas about what might be wrong?

**Solution** add full path of chpasswd:

```
echo "user_$1:$2" | /usr/sbin/chpasswd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, to further investigate shell execution problems from PHP, use:

```
exec("$command $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 2>&1", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: ############### Mo 16. Dez 14:39:01 CET 2013 ##################
Anzahl: 1 <<<<<<<<<<<< PwUpdate 5001 malta >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>root/cronscripts/pw.sh: 4: /cronscripts/pw.sh: chpasswd: not foundarray(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(62) "/cronscripts/pw.sh: 4: /cronscripts/pw.sh: chpasswd: not found"
}
Getting closer there musst be a different shell environment somehow i will need to put in the path to chpasswd

Comment: The new password comes from a webinterface... the useradd.php loads the pw from mysql.
I am on ubuntu 12.04 and will try to link againgst /usr/sbin/chpasswd

Comment: I see... o.k... Using full path to chpasswd solves your issue?

Comment: still testing but on a first impression it seems to fix the problem